# How do I make the program wait for a button click to go to the next loop iteration in a method? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, pause

I've made an algorithm that has many loops in it, and I'm trying to step through it with the click of the button. I need to be able to carry out just one iteration of the loop the first time I click a button, and then carry out the next iteration when I click it again, and so on until the program is finished. Can I accomplish that using JavaScript? If so, how?

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you looking for a debugger with breakpoints? Or does it need to be a button on the website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean an simple way to do this is with Promises, and using async / await.

Basically make your button click into a promise resolver that your wait function can pass.

Example below.

```js
let waitForPressResolve;

function waitForPress() {
    return new Promise(resolve => waitForPressResolve = resolve);
}

const btn = document.querySelector('button');

function btnResolver() {
  if (waitForPressResolve) waitForPressResolve();
}

async function doIt() {
  btn.addEventListener('click', btnResolver);
  for (let c = 1; c < 10; c += 1) {
    console.log(c);
    await waitForPress();
  }
  btn.removeEventListener('click', btnResolver);
  console.log('Finished');
}


doIt();
```

```html
<button>Do Next</button>
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the event listeners again once the button is clicked, otherwise this will leak memory

Comment: @Bergi  In the above example the event listener is only ever added once.  But it's a good point, especially if you used this in say a React app, remember to remove the event on dismount etc.  I'll update to put the remove in..